# Integration services project - Exporting to Excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, integration, business-intelligence

im trying to export a table from sql 2008R2 to Excel and when i run the package, it drops an error which tells me that the database engine Microsoft Jet can't open the file and says it's opened in exclusive mode by another user or that i need permission to see the data.

I'm running this locally from adventureworkds database. Thank you in advance!

### [image]

> SSIS package "Package3.dtsx" starting.
>   Error: 0xC0202009 at Package3, Connection manager "DestinationConnectionExcel": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "El motor de base de datos Microsoft Jet no puede abrir el archivo ''. Está abierto en modo exclusivo por otro usuario o bien necesita permiso para ver sus datos.".
>   Error: 0xC00291EC at Preparation SQL Task 1, Execute SQL Task: Failed to acquire connection "DestinationConnectionExcel". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.
>   Task failed: Preparation SQL Task 1
>   SSIS package "Package3.dtsx" finished: Failure.

Comment: Is Excel open? If so, close it

Comment: http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/file-in-use-by-another-process.html Something has a hook into the file. Read up on how to use Process Explorer to find the process and kill it.

Comment: i searched for any .xls or .xlsx file, and it doesnt show none.

Comment: Now im getting this error that the database engine Microsoft Jet cant find the object 'categories' and i have to make sure if it exist. But the exporting process has to create that on excel. Therefore it doesnt exist i guess.

Comment: Error: 0xC002F210 at Preparation SQL Task 1, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "CREATE TABLE `Categories` (
`CategoryID` Long,
`Ca..." failed with the following error: "El motor de base de datos Microsoft Jet no pudo encontrar el objeto 'Categories'. Asegúrese de que el objeto existe, y que ha escrito el nombre y la ruta de acceso al objeto correctamente.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
Task failed: Preparation SQL Task 1

Answer (score 0):

looks like the file is already open in excel and sql can't get access to it. just close the file in excel and it should work...

Comment: No, i dont have any excel file opened